Sending audio chunk to ICECAST on Azurecast "Streamer"
I am trying to connect to Azuracast Streamer using ICECAST, and stream audio chunks to it.
I am able to establish connection to ICECAST but each audio chunk I send through the socket is treated as a new file "For each chunk a new file is created", instead of concatenating it with the old chunk.
try {
      // Establish TCP connection to the Icecast server
      _socket = await Socket.connect(serverAddress, int.parse(port));
      isActive = _socket != null;

      if (isActive) {
        // Prepare and send the Icecast headers
        String auth = base64Encode(utf8.encode('$username:$password'));
        String headers = 'SOURCE $mountPoint HTTP/1.0\r\n'
            'Authorization: Basic $auth\r\n'
            'Content-Type: audio/mpeg\r\n'
            'Ice-Public: 1\r\n'
            'Ice-Name: My Radio\r\n'
            'Ice-Description: Flutter Streaming\r\n'
            'Ice-Audio-Info: ice-samplerate=$sampleRate;ice-bitrate=$bitRate;ice-channels=$channel\r\n'
            'Ice-Url: http://$serverAddress\r\n'
            'Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n'; 

        _socket!.add(utf8.encode(headers));

        // Log the connection status
        debugPrint('Connected to Icecast server');

        // Start listening to the input stream and server responses
        _startListening();

        return null;
      } else {
        return 'Failed to connect to Icecast server';
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // Return the error message
      return 'Init failed: $e';
    }


It's not entirely clear where the issue is from the code you've shown.  Where's the code where you're actually sending the data?  You're maintaining the same TCP connection as you send, right?  In any case, your header block isn't quite correct.  You need another \r\n at the end of all the headers before the request body data (the stream).  Also, it isn't going to matter in this case, but those headers need to be in ASCII, not UTF-8... something to keep in mind if you start adding descriptions with extended characters.
